# Rails ActiveJob Job with sidekiq delaying 6/10 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am using Rails ActiveJob with Sidekiq. 
I have a Job that is supposed to execute after 5 seconds.

```
UserArrivalJob.set(wait: 5.seconds).perform_later(user, planet)
```

Only after 5 seconds the job still hasnt ran.
When i look in the sidekiq web interface after those 5 seconds the job is there and it says: Not yet enqueued. After about another 6 till 10 seconds the job gets enqeued and is immediatly executed.
How come that there is this delay?
When i use perform now this delay is not there.

Here is my Job:

```
class UserArrivalJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user, planet)
    user.planet = planet
    user.save
  end
end
```

Comment: When you delay it like this, it's probably gets actually enqueued by another job which just doesn't run that often.

Comment: This is the only Job i have, do you know how to speed up the enqueing job?

Comment: If I were you, I'd start reading activejob code now. Let's say, it's possible. This will mean more resource consumption overhead (more frequent polling of delayed jobs queue, etc.) Is this delay of several seconds critical? Can't your app just tolerate it?

Comment: You can try `resque job`.  These are damn faster.

Comment: No its a game where you travel and it says you arrive in 10 seconds. So it comes down to the second.

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs#checking-for-new-jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcd was right. I set the sidekiq configuration to run the poller every 2 seconds.

**environments/development.rb / environments/production.rb**

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.average_scheduled_poll_interval = 2
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [here](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/wiki/Configuration). Basically I think your sidekiq poller runs every 10 seconds and it picks the job when it pools.